# Harnack's inequality of elliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, elliptic-functions, elliptic-equations

This problem is on page 334 of Evan's PDE book, where he states the Harnack's
inequality and refers the reader to Gilbarg-Trudinger [G-T] for the general situation. But in [G-T], that is, *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order*, I can only find the proof when the underlying space is $\mathbb{R}^2$. For the higher dimension counterparts, this proof is invalid and I failed to adapt it to this case. I want to know where I can find the proof of the
Harnack's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

It is in Gilbarg-Trudinger on page 199.

Comment: I got it, but it is stated and proved in a more general setting. Since I don't know the theory of the Sobolev space, I wonder if there is an elementary proof for the classical solution by a maximal principle argument.